# Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am using Android studio 2.3, gradle 3.3 and keep getting error(s) like

Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
...

app build.gradle contains

minSdkVersion 17, targetSdkVersion 23, compileSdkVersion 25

Complete build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<appname>"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            //applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            //versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'

            // debug and dev have the same apk signature,
            // so they can share an authority name
            resValue "string", "content_provider", "<appname>.debug.fileprovider"
            resValue "string", "fb_provider_id", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<providerid>"

        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            // debug and dev have the same apk signature,
            // so they can share an authority name
            resValue "string", "content_provider", "<appname>.fileprovider"
            resValue "string", "fb_provider_id", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<providerid>"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('lib/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
    // https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ueb.png)

I have searched throug SO, but I just can't solve this (by my own) so would be grateful for any explanation(s) how to fix the issue and how to determine what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I think your 25 completely not updated, so use build 25 to 24.

Comment: I tried changing to 24 but still having same issue - is it possible to find out which of the including libs is trying to reference v23/v24?